# Passing a hidden variable as a Session to another page in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, hidden

I have a hidden variable with no values. The value is defined when the user clicks submit, some data is sent to a javascript file and from there back to the hidden variable.

Im now trying to pass that variable as a session to another page but it wont work.

Thats my html

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" 
    onclick="susername(document.getElementById('fname').value, document.getElementById('lname').value ), 
                document.getElementById('address').value;">&nbsp;
<input type="reset"  value="Reset"/></td></tr>
<input type="hidden" value="" name="myhidden" id="myhidden"/>
```

This is my JS

```
function susername(first, last, address) {
    var lastname = last.charAt(0);
    document.getElementById('myhidden').value = total;
```

This is my php

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['myhidden'])){
    $hidden = $_POST["myhidden"];
    $_SESSION["hide"] = $hidden;
}
```

This is my php on the other page

```
session_start();
$sysuname = $_SESSION["hide"];
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: You'll have to explain that javascript? It gets the first character in lastname, then tries to concat to that single character, so how does  that work exactly ?

Comment: pretty much getting the first letter of the last name and the first name and getting the first letter from the address field. Putting it all together.

For example: First name: Test
             Last name: User
             Address: 123 Program road
this will become 

UTP @adeneo

Comment: But those are strings, concat is an Array method ?

Comment: i have two arrays, one for the date and one for the seconds. Didnt want to put that up just incase one of my teacher's find it, might get in trouble for asking for help

Comment: is the second page located on the same domain?

Comment: yeh its on the same domain, its another form, so i can fill out that form but when i click submit the hidden value doesnt go into the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all:

```
susername(document.getElementById('fname').value, document.getElementById('lname').value ), document.getElementById('address').value;">
```

You have bracket issue here

```
susername(document.getElementById('fname').value, document.getElementById('lname').value , document.getElementById('address').value);">
```

Comment: oh my f'ing god. That was the problem. Thank you so much, i have been trying to figure this out for hours.